# Closed Loop Control of BLDC Motor using STM32

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, commutation

I am working on 6-step commutation control of BLDC Motor. For this, I am using the values of Hall Sensors embedded inside the motor as feedback to determine the sector and find a switching sequence for my motor.

For hall sensors placed 120 degree electrically apart, the sequence in which the motor rotates is **5 - 1 - 3 - 2 - 6 - 4**.

The values of Hall sensors for the above sequence are:

**Hall A     Hall B     Hall C     Sector**

1            0          1           5

0            0          1           1

0            1          1           3

0            1          0           2

1            1          0           6

1            0          0           4

When I give this sequence in Simulink using STM32 Microcontroller to generate PWM signals for the Inverter as shown in figure below, the motor **runs with a little jerks but that doesn't matter.**

[image]

But when I give the Hall Sensors Input to the controller (as shown in figure below) to read the values and give sector and generate PWM signals according to it. When I turn ON the supply to the Inverter, motor **does not run**. However, the controller reads the values of Hall Sensors on which position the rotor of motor is at initially, and also gives values for switches correctly, but it does not move towards the next position and hence, switching states also not change.

I have set the sample time of the GPIO Pins of the Hall Sensors as 0.001 sec.

[image]

What could be the possible reasons and solutions for this issue?

Comment: Try swapping two phases or hall inputs.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead It didn't work in my case.

Comment: Does the motor vibrate when the halls are connected?

Comment: Yes, it moves to and fro on its initial position and does not take the next step.

Comment: Try all combinations of hall wires and motor wires, and with each combination give the motor shaft a little twist in each direction and see if it starts turning on its own,.  You might be current limiting.  Also try inverting your logic.  Remember that when a hall device is 'ON' its out put is low.